# ReactJs App's mapped list of buttons from Json file only have the last value of json array

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I am making list of button that will lead to different YouTube videos on ReactJs page. The issue is that when I map the links from json file (which contains video links), all the buttons get the last link of the mapped array. I need a way that all the rendered buttons will get their respective links. My code is below, I am using react ModalVideo to show my YouTube video.

```
    <ul className="list-unstyled">
         {datalist.lectures.map((value, index) => { 
                return  (
          <li key={index}>
          <ModalVideo channel='youtube' autoplay isOpen={isOpen} videoId={value} onClose={() => setOpen(false)} />
          
          <button className="play-icon" onClick={()=> setOpen(true)}> <i className="las la-play"></i> Lecture: {index+1}</button>
          </li>
                         )})}
          </ul>
```

All the links are coming from Json file where the code looks like this

```
 "lectures": [
                "BT4YihNXiYw",
                "NSFLhnv2pQI",
                "sEPxqpFZit8",
                "fU8QhoUJ_sE",
                "r3XFYOtvUng",
                "MZAkMddxhpg"
                 ]
```

I think the problem I have right now is that after the page render and mapping ends it only remembers what the last link is store in value, because of that no matter which button i click it shows me the last value of the mapped array

Comment: Are you constructing the link in child element based on the value from lectures array?

Comment: Do add a unqiue key to your <li>. Here your key can be value.

Comment: @TusharShahi Shahi i am making the link based on as many values i have in lectures array, also i tried adding key={value} in <li>, it still doesnot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some quick ideas looking at the minimal snippets available.

1. let's not to render multiple `ModalVideo` component like above, move it out from the `map`.
2. Use another state to keep track the change of the youtube videos' ID.

For example

```js
const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [videoId, setVideoId] = useState(null);
const playVideo = (vid) => {
    setOpen(true);
    setVideoId(vid);
};

return (
    <div>
        <ModalVideo
            channel='youtube'
            autoplay
            isOpen={isOpen}
            videoId={videoId}
            onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        />
        <ul className="list-unstyled">
            {
                datalist.lectures.map((value, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <button className="play-icon" onClick={() => playVideo(value)}>
                                <i className="las la-play"></i>
                                Lecture: {index + 1}
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    )
                })
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it works perfectly now, i needed to change the brackets of const {videoId, setVideoId} = useState(null); to const [videoId, setVideoId] = useState(null); otherwise it says its not function. Thankyou again @ChinKang

Comment: you're right, excuse me for not writing in javascript for more than a year. I will edit the above, thanks